# Adding background image to a portfolio project I'm creating but it's not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am working on a small portfolio project and want to use a background image in the home section I created. While everything (the code) looks ok, the background property `background: url();` and `background-image: ();` aren't working. I have looked through the code over and again but I can't find the problem.

I tried to use a web hosted image thinking it was a problem with the local images but that didn't work either. However, when I tried to implement the same process on an old project to confirm I wasn't making a mistake, it worked as expected.

Need help understanding what's wrong.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300&display=swap');
:root {
  --main-color: #0B192E;
  --main-lite-color: #233554;
  --font-color: #BEC8E9;
  --font-dark-color: #8892b0;
  --font-lite-color: #ccd6f6;
  --box-color: #112240;
  --style-color: #52D2B9;
  --main-font: 'Poppins';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: var(--main-font), sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background: var(--main-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
}


/* header styling */

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 9%;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a.active {
  color: var(--style-color);
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}


/* header styling end */


/* Intro/home section styling */

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10rem 9% 2rem;
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 9%;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/05/08/13/24/laptop-7978588_960_720.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.home-content {
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.home-content h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.home-content h1 span {
  color: var(--style-color);
}

.home-content h2 {
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.home-content .text-animation {
  position: relative;
  width: 35rem;
}

.home-content .text-animation h3 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px var(--style-color);
}

.home-content p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.contact-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 35rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.contact-btn .btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--style-color);
  border: .2rem solid var(--style-color);
  border-radius: .8rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: var(--main-color);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-btn .btn:hover {
  color: var(--style-color);
}

.contact-btn .btn:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--style-color);
}

.contact-btn .btn:nth-child(2):hover {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.contact-btn .btn:nth-child(2)::before {
  background: var(--style-color);
}

.contact-btn .btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--main-color);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-btn .btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4rem;
  width: 170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* .social-icons::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: .1rem;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--style-color);
    transform: rotate(90deg);   
    top: -.45rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
} */

.social-icons a {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: .2rem solid var(--style-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--style-color);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social-icons a:hover {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.social-icons a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--style-color);
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.social-icons a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Intro/home section styling end */
```

```html
<!-- header design -->
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">Adewale.</a>

  <div class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#education">Education</a>
    <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- header design end -->

<!-- home section design -->

<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="home-content">
    <h1>Hi, <span>my name is</span></h1>
    <h2>Adewale Mudasiru</h2>
    <div class="text-animation">
      <h3>Front-end Developer</h3>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium esse quos sapiente pariatur, maiores nisi itaque praesentium. Neque, assumenda fugit praesentium, accusamus asperiores explicabo esse expedita ad aliquam, aspernatur reiciendis!</p>

    <div class="contact-btn">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Let's Talk</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Download CV</a>
    </div>

    <div class="social-icons">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mudasiru.wale/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ade_mudasiru"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/adewale-mudasiru/"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- home section design end -->


<script src="assets/main.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting the background-image to appear in the home section and the code snippet seems to also work. What are you not seeing??

Comment: The image doesn't appear when I load the HTML on my browser.

Comment: it's working as expected, do you have a link where it's not working ?

Comment: don't debug your code from the IDE, use dev tools for such thing... my bet is that a javascript script error is causing this. go to inspect and check : 1) if console has errors. 2) inspect the body style.

Comment: I found the problem. I'm not sure how it happened. I had two CSS files on the project containing the same style. I must have duplicated the original CSS without knowing. Thanks a lot.